# Fastest way to clear Nephalem Rifts?

Tags: diablo-iii

One of the achievements is to clear a Rift in just 2 short minutes. So seeing there isn't a difficulty requirement, I went to Normal to give this a try. After a few attempts my fastest time is still around 9 minutes. How is it possible to clear Rifts in just 2 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get this achievement is to join the game of a friend when the rift guardian spawns in his rift, kill the guardian then finish the mission in town. Since you wont spent more than 2 min killing the guardian, it will unlock the achievement. That's how I got it, even though I didn't know I would (I was just helping my friend to finish because he was having a hard time)

This however is not a "legit" 2min clear but just a trick to get the achievement. If you want to clear it in a legit way the easiest way is to do it with 4 players in normal. Everyone split on the map and with some practice, you should be able to achieve under 2 min quite easily.

### Some tips

- The fastest class is the Demon Hunter : Vault + Tactical Advantage offer a constant high speed and you can use skills like Multishot (with suppression fire) for Huge AoE + big damage. Then With preparation (backup plan) and companion (bat) you will never run out of ressources.
- A cool trick is one person TP and wait in the town to complete the msision while the Guardian spawns. It saves a little bit more time.

In any way it require luck. Not all rift are achievable in under 2 min because of their monster density and the pattern of the map.

Comment: Instead of suppression fire multishot, you might also take ball lightning elemental arrow, which I think hits more enemies (sometimes twice), does only slightly less damage, and costs 10 hatred.

Comment: @MrLemon I disagree : When you don't have the Danetta Set, Suppression fire restore up to 6 discipline per shot on big pack allowing to vault way more. If you use preparation with punishement instead of back up  plan and pick night stlaker as a passive you are guaranteed to being able to vault and use this big AoE to regen discipline without worrying about ressource costs.

Comment: Okay, I have mixed up the runes, thought that suppressive fire was the hatred reduction rune.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to clear a rift is by using a level 1 rifts. Step by step explanation:

1. Find 3 friends who want to get this achievement as well. Preferably if they are DH's with both Danetta's xbows
2. One of you creates a new character, then creates a game where everybody joins
3. Re-join with the level 70(or 60) DH and let somebody open the rift
4. Now there are 4 level 60-70 guys in a Normal level 1 game ==> every monster will die with a single hit
5. Spread out, kill everything as fast as you can.
6. If you are lucky, you will get the achievement after the first try. If not, open another rift and repeat

Comment: The timer stops when you speak to Orek, so one person should start teleporting to town the moment the Guardian becomes imminent.

Answer (score -1):

I completed the achievement with 3 friends. However, we weren't trying to get the achievement or anything; just farming rifts. We were on Expert difficulty as well. My thoughts about it are that it just depends on the rift and monster density. It's definitely very possible to complete the achievement on harder difficulties, so if you're having a rough time with grabbing the achievement, maybe just get better equipment, paragon levels, etc.

Comment: There's no information that was not covered in previous answers :-(